# How to erase the text input that the user typed using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

```
<div class = "search ui-widget">
    <label for = "keyword"></label>
    <input type="text" id="keyword" onkeypress="searchKeyPress(event)" placeholder="Search here" required>
    <input type="button" id="btnSearch" onclick="loadDeals('search', keyword.value,'')"  />
</div>


$('.search input#keyword').Value('');
```

Basically what I want is to remove the user's input in the text box after the user clicks another menu tab. I tried `$('.search input#keyword').Value('');` and `$('.search input#keyword').css("value", '');` but it didn't work.

Comment: The method is called `.val()` instead of `.Value()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**.val()**](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is the right name of the jQUery method, not `Value()`.

You can use jQuery like this:

```
 $('#keyword').val('');
```

Or you can use plain javascript like this:

```
 document.getElementById('keyword').value = '';
```

---

If there are more input fields beside the ones you posted  and you want to clear all inputs you can use:

```
$('.search input').val('');
```

Comment: @user2625152, glad I could help. Please click to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure javascript solution:

```
document.getElementById('keyword').value = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$("the_class_or_id").val("");
```

Link for this: [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

This is introduced in jQuery API. You can use `.value` in JavaScript, but in jQuery its `val()`. It gets the value of the object and to clear the value, just add quotes!

JavaScript code would be:

```
document.getElementById("id_name").value = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Since HTML id attributes are supposed to be unique I would recommend not using the '#keyword' id in your jquery selector.  The solution does work if there's only one text field, but it isn't scalable to multiple text fields.  Instead, I would make 'keyword' a class for the input element and use the selector:

```
$('.search input.keyword').val('');
```

This is very similar to the solution Sergio gave except it allows you to control, via the 'keyword' class, which input elements have their values cleared.